# How to enable symbol browser in CodeBlocks20.03?

Tags: codeblocks

The version I used is 20.03 which released on 2020/7/03. This version is 20.03-r11983.

When I tried to open Symbols Browsser, it pops up `The symbols browser is disabled in wx3.x builds. We've done this because it causes ceashes`.

I've searched on Bing (Google is not available in my country), found that they fixed the issue it in later builds. But they are nightly builds and there's no setup.exe I can directly run.

Because I'm a starter, I'm not familiar with configuring the compiler and debugger. As for this, the nightly build maynot suitable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try one of the "Unofficial Code::Blocks Installers" as they are rebuilt quite often. Link is to forum topic at Code::Blocks

[Unofficial Code::Blocks installer for Windows x64 August 2021](https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,24592.0.html)